# On windows build fails cannot open/find include file

Tags: cmake, windows, ros-humble

I'm trying to build a mini toy project on windows (ros humble) and 1 package (the last one) fails to build throwing the error fatal  error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'test_actions/actions.hpp': No such file or directory.

`test_actions/actions.hpp` is in the expected place (`install/include/test_actions/test_actions/actions.hpp`)

It does not complain about headers from other packages which are also built.

The cmake file for the package is

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(test_project)

set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

# find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
find_package(behaviortree_cpp REQUIRED)
find_package(test_actions REQUIRED)

set(MAIN_APPLICATION my_app)

add_executable(${MAIN_APPLICATION} src/my_application.cpp)
target_include_directories(${MAIN_APPLICATION} PRIVATE
  $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
  $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>)
ament_target_dependencies(${MAIN_APPLICATION} rclcpp test_actions behaviortree_cpp)
target_compile_features(${MAIN_APPLICATION} PUBLIC c_std_99 cxx_std_17)  # Require C99 and C++17

install(
    TARGETS ${MAIN_APPLICATION}
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
    LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
    RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)

ament_export_dependencies(behaviortree_cpp rclcpp test_actions)

ament_package()
```

Even stranger is the test_actions package use to also contain message definitions, and at that time this `test_project` package did build, but I had runtime issues with the custom message definitions so did the recommended solution of breaking them out into a separate package which solved those runtime issues, but now `test_project` fails to find `test_actions/actions.hpp` (but it does still install it to the correct location from a clean build).

I have tried many things like adding the fully qualified path to the `target_include_directories`, adding dependencies in different locations, etc etc but always can't find it. If I remove the include from `src/my_application.cpp` and comment out related code, the application builds and I can run it

Update: If change the include in the source file to `test_actions/test_actions/actions.hpp` it does find it

Update2: If I build on ubuntu VM it can't find it at either `test_actions/actions.hpp` or `test_actions/test_actions/actions.hpp` (but is still in the expected location)

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange!

As you have already found the solution, it seems that there is no need to add an answer to your question.